# vb. net split a huge string into words and get a (word) index

Tags: vb.net, string, search, split

I have a huge text file in arabic .. i want to search about any sentence and if i found it get the index of the first word .. i repeat (word) not character .. how to do this please ?

for example:

```
Dim myString as String = "Fundamentally programs manipulate numbers and text. These are the building blocks of all programs. Programming languages let you use them in different ways, eg adding numbers, etc, or storing data on disk for later retrieval"
```

so.. when i search about (programs) i want to return: 1 and 13 .. any suggestions by the best way ? thanx

Comment: Have you looked around for an answer? What have you tried? Although you already have an answer now, this would be very easy information to find with a simple Google search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you split the string into words. We will use this to conveniently remove punctuation as well (expand as necessary):

```
Dim words = myString.Split({". ", ", ", " "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Then you search for the word in question (case-insensitive):

```
Dim indexes = From i In Enumerable.Range(0, words.Length)
              Where String.Equals(words(i), "programs", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
              Select i
```

Then you output the result (optional):

```
For Each i In indexes
    Console.WriteLine(i)
Next
```

Comment: ok.. let me say that this is a very useful if i want to search about one word .. but what about (sentence).. please complete the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Split function`:

```
Dim array() As String = Split(myString, " ")
```

In case you want to split by spaces. Then if you want to get the n position just use `array(n-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Dim line As String = "hello    world"
        Dim words As String() = line.Split(New Char() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
words(index)
```

or

```
  Dim line As String = "hello    world"
        Dim words As String() = line.Split(New Char() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(index)
```